# wireshark how do I filter for items not in an array?

Tags: wireshark

the syntax;

```
tcp.port in {80 443 8080}
```

works great for filtering ports, but;

```
tcp.port not in {80 443 8080}
```

doesn't seem to be valid.

UPDATE:

how dumb am i...

```
not tcp.port in {80 443 8080}
```

this syntax works, will accept the answer to anyone that knows how i can use a file full of port numbers as the array though (csv or txt).

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same answer when I stumbled upon your question, however your update does not really do what you initially asked for. Suppose we have traffic between these ports:

```
Src    Dst
   80  10000
10000    443
10000  10000
   80   8080
```

the statement

```
tcp.port not in {80 443 8080}
```

is equivalent to

```
not tcp.srcport in {80 443 8080} or not tcp.dstport in {80 443 8080}
```

which will display all traffic where source or destination port was not in the group.

```
Src    Dst
   80  10000  <== displayed
10000    443  <== displayed
10000  10000  <== displayed
   80   8080  <== filtered
```

On the other hand

```
not tcp.port in {80 443 8080}
```

equates to

```
not(tcp.srcport in {80 443 8080} or tcp.dstport in {80 443 8080})
```

or when expanded

```
not tcp.srcport in {80 443 8080} and not tcp.dstport in {80 443 8080}
```

This will not display traffic where source or destination port is in the group.

```
Src    Dst
   80  10000  <== filtered
10000    443  <== filtered
10000  10000  <== displayed
   80   8080  <== filtered
```

Comment: I stumbled across this post & reply during a google search. I work with USBPcap and was looking for a solution of filtering USB devices that do not match a certain bus address. It seems that the elements should (must?) be separated by commas, so a valid syntax example for me is: `usb.addr not in {"2.13.3", "2.64.2", "2.16.0", "2.16.1", "2.8.0", "2.1.0", "2.4.0", "2.3.0", "2.64.0", "2.11.0", "2.13.0", "2.2.0", "2.14.0", "2.17.0", "2.62.0", "2.6.0", "2.62.1", "2.62.3", "2.17.1"}`